# SDL_RenderPresent() implementation

Tags: sdl-2

The SDL wiki says of `SDL_RenderPresent()`:

> SDL's rendering functions operate on a backbuffer; that is, calling a rendering function such as SDL_RenderDrawLine() does not directly put a line on the screen, but rather updates the backbuffer. As such, you compose your entire scene and present the composed backbuffer to the screen as a complete picture. Therefore, when using SDL's rendering API, one does all drawing intended for the frame, and then calls this function once per frame to present the final drawing to the user. **The backbuffer should be considered invalidated after each present**; do not assume that previous contents will exist between frames. You are strongly encouraged to call SDL_RenderClear() to initialize the backbuffer before starting each new frame's drawing, even if you plan to overwrite every pixel.

Why is the backbuffer invalidated? I'd like to optimize rendering performance by only redrawing parts of the rendering target that *need* to be redrawn. How can I do this if the backbuffer is invalidated? The Win32 API allows one to redraw portions of the rendering target. Why not SDL?

Comment: SDL have multiple implementations; if at least one potentially invalidates backbuffer (e.g. creating new backbuffer on each swap) - SDL can't promise you to keep that. You can always verify your particular implementation with GL, d3d or whatever you use manual. However, it makes a very little sense - even if backbuffer data is kept, it'll be lagging 1 frame behind, so updating it'd be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

When you call present SDL sends the backbuffer to be displayed and it swaps it out thus the new backbuffer is garbage and you have to redraw it again, this is done for performance reasons.

What I think you can do if you're not modifying the whole screen is try to minimize draw calls by using your own backbuffer and then presenting that, something along the lines of:

```
// we'll use this texture as our own backbuffer
SDL_Texture *buffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888,
                                        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, w, h); 
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, buffer); // all the draw calls go to buffer instead of the sdl backbuffer
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, some_texture, src_rect, dst_rect); // for example this would draw to buffer
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL); // we set the renderer back so we can draw to the SDL backbuffer
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, buffer, src_rect, dst_rect); // copy our own backbuffer in one call
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

With this you can minimize draw calls since you'll be updating your own backbuffer and then presenting that instead of redrawing the whole screen each time.